# How to use Principal component Analysis(PCA) to extract feature from images

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, machine-learning

How can use principal component Analysis to extract feature from image that is been acquired by the camera?

Comment: There are some applications where PCA used, like Face Recognition.Your question is too broad. Which type of features you mean? Please be SPECIFIC.

Answer (score 1):

PCA is mostly used to reduce the dimensionality of the features.

You should first use a feature detector before you can use PCA to reduce the dimensions of these features. Common feature detectors are SIFT, SURF, ORB etc. Some of them are even available in OpenCV.